# Show Toast notification if EditText is empty

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have 7 Edit Text fields in my Activity

I have values where text from EditText  is writing

For example:

```
EditText misto = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.misto) ;
city = misto.Text;
```

How I can check empty EditText and don't start new activity when user don't fill all fields?

I using Xamarin (c#) for making Android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(misto.Text))
{
   // do something
}
```

to check for empty strings.

Comment: Thank's dude, it helped me

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.